# Find condtion of A is a bijective

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(X,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal system $\{e_n\}$ and $\{\lambda_k\}$ is a bounded sequence. We define
$A(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$ and $A_n(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$, $x \in X$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have already proved $A: X \rightarrow X$ is linear and continuous and $\Vert A \Vert =\displaystyle\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \vert \lambda_k \vert $.

I tried to find a necessary and sufficent condtion of A is a bijective, but I don't have any idea.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle x,e_k\rangle,$ not $<x,e_k>. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is bijective then it has  a continuous inverse by Open Mapping Theorem. Since $Ae_k=\lambda_k e_k$ it follows that $\frac 1 {\lambda_k}e_k=A^{-1} e_k$ is bounded. So $\inf \{|\lambda_k|: k \geq 1 \} >0$.

Conversely, suppose $\inf \{|\lambda_k|: k \geq 1 \} >0$.  If $Ax=Ay$ then $\lambda_k \langle x, e_k \rangle=\lambda_k \langle y, e_k \rangle$ for all $k$ which gives $x=y$. Any $y =\sum a_ke_k \in X$ (with $\sum |a_k|^{2}< \infty$)  is the image of $\sum \frac {a_k} {\lambda_k} e_k$ so $A$ is also surjective.

Comment: Your post has a set $H$, I don't know what is $H$?

Comment: @NguyenThy That was supposed to be $X$.